# Many to Many Relation (Set)

Tags: java, set, relation, hateoas, hypermedia

What is the best way to design a many to many relation with `hateoas`?
I have a bidirectional relation between two classes, defined with a `Set`.

My problems are the `POST` / `PUT` methods for binding one resource to the other.
(Making a Relation)

Example:

```
class A {
    int id;
    String nameOfA = "A";
    Set<B> set;
}

class B {
    int id;
    String nameOfB = "B";
    Set<A> set;
}
```

First way: resource uris could be

```
/A/{aid}/B/{bid}
/B/{bid}/A/{aid}
```

For adding a relation between `A` with id 1 and `B` with id 2 I would make a `POST` on: `/A/1/B/2` or `/B/2/A/1`.

Second way:

For adding a relation between `A` with id 1 and `B` with id 2 `POST` on `/A/1/B` with a "B-object" as content:

```
{id:2,nameOfB:"B"}
```

Which is the better way or are there even better solutions? Thanks for help :)

Comment: sry this doesn't help me. My question is what is the "RESTful" way to solve this? Making Resources like way1 or way2?

Comment: Okay. Why not hit an endpoint with `{"A":1, "B":2}`? Same endpoint for all, right?

Comment: If it's directional you could do `{"A":1, "B":2, "to":"B"}` (or `"to":"A"`)

Comment: hmm thats a good point but i don't like it :D,  i would need a virtual key for this relation or? - {id:1, "A":1, "B":2}

Comment: you mean a link to A/B?

Comment: What I'm saying with that is that you have an `A` with the ID `1`, a `B` with the ID `2`, and the direction is from the `A` `"to"` the `B`. You can omit `"to"` if your relation is not directional.

Comment: well the relation is bidirectional. is there. But how a rest client easy finds all a B to the A with the id 1.

Comment: If it's bidirectional then just `POST` the JSON `{"A":1, "B":2}` to a hypothetical `relation` endpoint. Super easy.